# I consistently get two login screens

Tags: login, login-screen

> I consistently get two login screens!
>
> I enter credentials correctly and am immediately presented with a second login screen (no errors). Authenticating against the second screen completes a normal login to the Ubuntu desktop.

The above is a quotation from a problem reported on 7. May 2012 by Soren Mogensen. See [User login cycles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130044/user-login-cycles). I have the exact same problem, and was hoping that Soren might have received an answer which would enlighten others, but unfortunately Soren's problem was reported as part of an "answer" to another problem, and the only "solution" on that occasion was advice to create a new question.

I can login, I just have to present my credentials twice, so this is NOT a duplicate of any "unable to login" problem. My concern is that this looks like a classic phishing setup, where one of the two login screens is a fake designed to harvest my ID and password for some nefarious purpose. If Ubuntu has been susceptible to phishing attacks for nearly a year now, then I imagine that would be a matter of enormous concern.

Comment: Here a bug that could be related https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1296270

Comment: I'm seeing this on an [Ubuntu GNOME](https://ubuntugnome.org/download/) installation. The top-rated answer below is not plausible because `Package 'gnome-screensaver' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: Just to re-iterate @charneykaye comment:  
this **does not work** on Lubuntu 16.04 where gnome-screensaver is also **not** installed.

Comment: *it seems* (by my own passive self-observation) this issue is avoided if I  wait a few seconds before entering my info, after boot/wakeup.

Comment: Same thing for me - happens after sleep.
No gnome screensave
LightDm owns xorg:
systemd-+-accounts-daemon-+-{gdbus}
        |                 `-{gmain}
        |-lightdm-+-Xorg---{InputThread}
        |         |-lightdm-+-upstart-+-at-spi-bus-laun-+-dbus-daemon

Answer (score 13):

Uninstall your gnome-screensaver,

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

Then, reboot. It works for me, now only unity login screen appears.

Comment: this worked for me on 16.04

Comment: Worked for me on 14.04. Don't forget to restart! I had to force a reboot.

Comment: I can confirm, this worked as a solution on another related question +1

Comment: And, the screensaver also keeps working after.

Comment: it not working me on 18.04

Answer (score 1):

1. Try `sudo pstree`

   You should look for the `Xorg` process and see what parent it has.
   Is that parent process `lightdm`?

   Then you're using the LightDM display manager, and it's proboably a LightDM issue.
2. Install another display manager, `GDM`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdm
   ```

   During configuration of the package, set GDM as the display manager.

   Does the problem still exist?
   Now you're sure it's a LightDM issue.
3. ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
   ```

   Now LigthDM is back.

Comment: Thanks. The parent process of Xorg was KDM. I switched to lightdm, got the message Please be sure to run "dpkg --configure lighttdm", so I did that (with sudo) and got the message.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to post a multi-paragraph response here, but every time I press return it seems to post my message instead of starting a new paragraph. Anyway, the parent process of Xorg was KDM. I installed and switched to lightdm, and got the message 'Please be sure to run "dpkg --configure lighttdm"', so I did that (with sudo) and got messages 'package lightdm is already installed and configured' and 'errors were encountered while processing: lightdm'. The system now hangs on reboot, so I'm working on rebooting without the GUI in order to then get things back the way they were before.

Comment: Now I've got it booting again and set GDM as the display manager. I still get two login screens in succession but they look different now, and are accompanied by a musical note.

Comment: Getting weirder. I've switched to lightdm again and this time it doesn't hang, but now it boots straight to the desktop. I'm able to use the desktop for a minute or two, and only THEN does a login screen appear.

Comment: Finally I've switched the display manager back to KDM, which is what it was originally. I still get two login screens, one after the other, but since the alternative display managers seem to be as bad or worse, I think I'll leave well alone. Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: Today I've uninstalled Nanoweb, a web server written in PHP, and the problem has gone away. I've rebooted a couple of times to check, and each time I now only need to present my credentials once. This may be a coincidence, or it may be that Nanoweb was somehow the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off **Screen Reader**

To do this:

1. Go to **System Settings** > **Universal Access**
2. Under the **Seeing** tab, turn **OFF**- **Screen Reader**

Answer (score -1):

This solution seems to work for some as it looks like an ongoing problem depending on circumstances - Look in your system settings for "Lock Screen" in all possible applications.

1. Search dash or in system settings go to **Brightness & Lock** then turn lock off.
2. Check in other apps like **Unity Tweak Tool > System** and uncheck **Desktop lock**.
3. Open a terminal and navigate to `/var/log/` then use `less auth.log` and check the log then check to see what happens at start if there any errors. Look out for pam-wallet issues like directory not found, error opening it. If you see wallet errors then try reinstalling - `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pam-kwallet`  then `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get -y autoclean && sudo apt-get -y clean`  finally `sudo apt-get update`. Reboot machine.
4. Reconfigure lightdm using commands below one by one

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge lightdm
   sudo apt-get install
   sudo apt-get install lightdm
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
   ```

Comment: that last set of commands is nonsense?