# Which package provides this login screen?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, unity-greeter, gnome-screensaver

I would like to identify the package that provides the following login screen:

[image: Login screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM), the package is `unity-greeter` and it is part of `lightdm`, these are the relevant files for customization

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Specifics can be found at the wiki link.

Comment: Thank you very much! Does the same package also provide [this](http://i.imgur.com/PbdbaAB.png) login screen or is this yet a different package?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know any log in screen etc is provided by the display manager (lightdm), the only time it is different is on another desktop (gdm for gnome etc..) but as long as you have unity `lightdm` should be what you need.

Comment: I see, thanks! Do you have any idea why I might see both? First, I see the one shown above, then after entering my password, I see the second one I just shared with you.

Comment: Seems that installing some gnome desktop packages can cause this, I would guess that the packages pull in some extra gnome stuff as dependencies. This answer had some success http://askubuntu.com/a/747888/75060 going off of comments, can you think of any gnome packages you may of installed?

Comment: Also, this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1292451 says it is related to the `gnome-screensaver` package.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your great help! I removed `gnome-screensaver` and this first annoying login-screen is finally gone. Great! :-)

Comment: Glad to help :)