# Double-login on 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, login

For the past week or two, I've noticed my login process to be slightly different than normal. This made me wonder if there is a security issue I should worry about. So I started searching here, but could not find a clear answer.

I see many questions about being caught in a "login loop" but that is not what is happening to me (at least I do not think so).

When I startup my laptop running 18.04 (encrypted boot drive, up to date OS) I have to enter my decryption password. This is as it has always been. Then, I am greeted with the normal login screen. I enter my password and it looks like it was accepted (no bad password message, the screen is all purple momentarily but I can still see the mouse cursor, but I cannot move it) and before the desktop background (or any desktop icons) shows, I am returned to the normal login screen. There is still no message to indicate that my password was wrong. I enter the password, again, and it starts as usual.

What is so strange to me is that this is always a double login. That is, it never prompts me only once and it never prompts me more than twice.

I looked for the `~/.xsession-errors` file but I do not seem to have it.

I've used this laptop for a year with 16.04 and I installed 18.04 just after it was released and there have been no hardware changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do these two login screen look identical? Could you add photos of them to your question if they're not?

Comment: @pomsky They are identical and look just like they always have.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-screensaver | grep Installed` in Terminal?

Comment: @pomsky "Installed: (none)"

Comment: Okay, so it seems this is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286637/i-consistently-get-two-login-screens).

Comment: @pomsky I tried [this answer from that question](https://askubuntu.com/a/286663/551485) but when I run pstree, I do not see any Xorg. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu so perhaps I'm missing something but I did look through the tree several times. Does this indicate anything?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue when upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04. For me it was related to Ubuntu switching from Xorg to Wayland.

When booting Ubuntu it was starting a Wayland session, but my user session was still configured to use Xorg from my 16.04 install, causing the double login scenario when it switches to Xorg. I was able to fix the issue by setting my user session to use `Ubuntu on Wayland`

[image: Login screenshot]

Comment: I'm having this same issue, and this solution "worked" but spawned another bug: the session logs me out after just a few seconds.

Comment: This did solve the double login issue, but some applications no longer worked (Mailspring and GParted for example wouldn't open)

Comment: After the double login, I get a black screen. Cannot access a terminal either. When I switch to ubuntu on Wayland gui that require root privileges fail with  Gtk-WARNING **: 15:09:56.627: cannot open display: :0. Since Wayland was replaced by xorg in 18.04 relying on Wayland seems a regression. Would like to figure out what the problem is with xorg.

Comment: To get root access to gui, I typed $ xhost + (in a terminal)

Answer (score 1):

i had the issue after upgrading from 16 to 18. And 'accidentally' fixed it after reinstalling the graphics card drivers. Anyone still having the issue might wanna try this as well.

Comment: I thought it might be a driver issue but my hard drive ended up failing (unrelated, I assume). Since reinstall, it does not happen but your idea seems reasonable to test.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this issue since upgrading from 18.04 LTS to 18.10. Logging into Ubuntu on Wayland (as John suggests above) did not work because the session would crash, logging me out after about five seconds of uptime.

I noticed that another option was listed under Ubuntu on Wayland, called Ukui, and when I logged into that everything was completely broken.

I uninstalled Ukui, and it fixed the problem! The double login screen is gone.

I don't know why this broken desktop environment was ever installed in the first place, but here's how I removed it:

```
sudo apt purge ukui-screensaver
```

I also found several other Ukui programs installed using this command

```
apt list --installed | grep ukui
```

... all of which I removed:

```
sudo apt remove libukui-menu2 libukui-panel-applet-4-1 python3-ukui-menu ukui-menus ukui-panel-common ukui-panel ukui-session-manager ukui-settings-daemon-common ukui-settings-daemon ukui-window-switch
```