# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Keyring error, Terminal Start Issue, Double Login

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

I have encountered a cacophony of bugs on Ubuntu 18.04.1. I believe the reasons for these bugs must be multifarious. However, I think one is definitely the recent update of Ubuntu I installed.

In order of discovery:

1. My computer asks for my login twice. My credentials are taken, but the original login screen is encountered and I must enter my credentials a second time. I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083102/double-login-on-18-04) that gives a workaround for the issue, which is to log in under Ubuntu on Wayland, but it does not SOLVE the issue.
2. Upon successful log in I receive the "the local keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer" error. It is not related to launching Chrome ([many users have this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31786/chrome-asks-for-password-to-unlock-keyring-on-startup)), but rather as soon as I log in to the Desktop.
3. I cannot always open the terminal. Logging into Ubuntu on Waylands seems to be a workaround to this issue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
I was able to get on the Terminal using login through Ubuntu on Wayland. I used sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get update. After restarting I was prompted to reset the password for the old keyring and a new keyring was added. I also found that chrome's remotedesktop was either partly or entirely to blame for the issue from a different post (I cannot find) and so uninstalled it from my computer and my browser and this seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: Interesting that you suspect chrome remote desktop.  I recently started seeing this same issue and when I read your post I realized that I had recently _also_ started using chrome remote desktop.  That at least points me in the right direction.  Thanks for that! ;-)

Comment: @aztlan2k You are welcome. Really glad I could help!